# Не получается переопределить функцию в файле plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно изменить вёрстку главной страницы магазина. Изменить количество столбцов с 4 на 3.
В файле **plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php** есть функция, отвечающая за количество столбцов товаров:

```
function wc_get_default_products_per_row() {
    $columns      = get_option( 'woocommerce_catalog_columns', 4 );
    ...
}
```

Я скопировал её в **function.php** моей темы, изменил количество столбцов и добавил перед ней удаление старого хука и добавление нового:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_get_default_products_per_row', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_get_default_products_per_row_1', 10);
function wc_get_default_products_per_row_1() {
        $columns      = get_option( 'woocommerce_catalog_columns', 3 );
        ...
    }
```

И woocommerce плевать хотел на это всё. Грузит старый хук, как будто нового нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, почему вы решили, что фильтр `_title` может иметь хоть какое-то отношение к столбцам.

Функция `wc_get_default_products_per_row()` фильтрует результат своей работы через `apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', $columns );`.

Это означает, что вам надо добавить такой код в `function.php` вашей темы:

```
function my_loop_shop_columns_filter( $columns ) {
    return 3;
}

add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'my_loop_shop_columns_filter' );
```

Comment: Блин, точно, _title. Я смотрел и в упор не видел, спасибо. Ваш код работает. Не подскажете, где можно почитать о том, как это всё работает и какие функции через что вызываются?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/hooks Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Галочку нажал, вверх тоже. Но у меня репы не хватает, чтобы цифра повысилась.

Comment: Да ок, спасибо за то, что отметили галочкой.